# Model Observer, not working for update?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, observer-pattern, observers

Im having trouble trying to get my model observer to work.. It is working as expected for create and deleted, but not for updating. Im guessing the event never fires. The thing is all of then are being done exactly the same way. Any ideas?
Below, my observer.

```
class GenericObserver extends AbstractObserver {

protected $events;

public function __construct(Dispatcher $dispatcher){
    $this->events = $dispatcher;

}

public function saved($model) {
    dd($this->events);

    $user_id = Auth::user()->usr_id;
    $user_nome = Auth::user()->usr_nome;
    $user_email = Auth::user()->usr_email;

    dd($model);
}

public function deleted($model) {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->usr_id;
    $user_nome = Auth::user()->usr_nome;
    $user_email = Auth::user()->usr_email;

    echo($model->getTable());
    dd($model->getKeyName());

}

public function updated($model) {


    $user_id = Auth::user()->usr_id;
    $user_nome = Auth::user()->usr_nome;
    $user_email = Auth::user()->usr_email;

    dd($model);

}

public function saving($model){
    echo 'Saving';
}

public function deleting($model){
    echo 'Deleting';
}

public function updating($model){
    echo 'Updating';
}
```

And here, my model class

```
Aplicacao extends Model {
protected $table = 'gst_aplicacoes';

protected $primaryKey = 'app_id';

protected $fillable = ['app_nome', 'app_key', 'app_observacao'];

public static function table() {
    $model = new static;
    return $model->getTable();
}

 public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();


    Aplicacao::observe(new GenericObserver(new Dispatcher));
}
```

Comment: I don't see 'updating'. In 'updated' is no change of $model.

Comment: Sorry, dont think i quite get it, what I want to do is, store the data of the model when an update happens, the thing is, it is working normally for create and deleted, both implemented the same way, but the updated event does not fire at all

Answer (score 9):

If anyone ever faces this issue, the reason the event was not firing was because the update method, only fire its events when the update happens directly on the model, since i was using an intermediary repository to represent my model, it wasn't working.

for more details.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11777#issuecomment-170388067

Comment: Thank you - I was going insane!

Comment: The reason is in this comment https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11777#issuecomment-170384117

Answer (score 3):

Observer work on only save() method. And it's not working on function of query builder that you call by magic methods. So on update() and created() observer is not work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

Model::find($id)->update(['column' => $value]);